# JavaScript object context and functions

Tags: javascript

In the below code snippet, why does window.foo exist, but this.bar is undefined?

```
function foo() { 
  function bar() {  }; 
  console.log(this.bar); 
}

console.log(window.foo);
foo.call({});
```

Comment: Because `this` in JavaScript` has nothing to do with variable scope. It's a dynamic value that is set based on how a function is invoked. The exception is the global environment where `this` refers to the global `window` object, which also holds the global variables.

Comment: `this` is looking for the `bar` method or object of the `global` object which would be `window`.  `bar` is undefined in the `global` object.

Comment: What is most confusing to me is that window.foo exists. Why is that happening at the global scope, but not in each child scope?

Comment: @LeeIrvine: Because. :-) At the global scope, `this` is the `window` object. The language spec says so.

Comment: `window.foo` exists because every time you make a variable or a function you're actually defining things in the `global` object... Which would be `window`.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: Actually in this case, `this` is the empty object passed when `foo()` is invoked. This is because OP is using `.call()` to invoke it. Same result though. There's no `.bar` property on it.

Comment: All global variables/functions are window.NAME

Comment: Basically, read the manual: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Right, but then why does window.foo exist? I never said window.foo = foo;

Comment: Like @Barmar said... all global variables become properties of `window` automatically. The reverse is true as well.

Comment: @squint Right you are.  `{}` is taking the place of `this` in that sense.  There is no `bar` there.  I overlooked that.

Comment: @LeeIrvine You don't have to.  When you write `function foo` you are literally making a method of the `global` object called `foo`.

Comment: @Sethen, so I guess at the global scope it's a special case? There is nothing similar as you move down the scope chain?

Comment: If you're defining functions globally, yes.  If you are writing methods inside of an object with `{}`, `this` would refer to the object in the question.

Comment: @LeeIrvine: There's no exposed variable object in the nested *(function)* scopes. There is however an `arguments` object that lets you reference the arguments passed to the function. No object for `var` or `function name() {...` declarations though.

Answer (score -1):

In a browser, window is a global object, so it's available everywhere unless it's shadowed. `this` is only pointing to something useful in the body of a function that's called as a method; in foo.bar() - where in `bar`, `this` is `foo`, or when bar.call(...) or bar.apply(...) is called with an argument for `this` or when you're outside of a function call altogether, where it points to the global object (window).

You're explicitly doing foo.call({}) which sets this to an empty Object. So this.bar does not exist during that call.